# Need to calculate the current date till end year?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports-2008

I am automating a report that currently has 3 dates set parameters, the user enters. Note our dates are in yyyymmdd format.

We want that the first set will be from the current date:
ToText(CurrentDate, 'yyyyMMdd') till end of year. I can hard code 20151231 but would prefer not to. How would you script this for last day of year?

Comment: Why not just go Year + '1231' ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a SQL Server of a recent-ish vintage:

- **Current Date:**
   
  `select today = convert(date, current_timestamp )`
- **1st Day of Current Month:**
  `select first_of_month = convert(date,
     dateadd(day, 1-day(current_timestamp) , current_timestamp )
   )`
- **Last Day of Current Month:**
  `select last_of_month = convert(date,
     dateadd(day, 1-day(dateadd(month,1,current_timestamp)) ,
       dateadd(month,1,current_timestamp)
     )
   )`
- **1st Day of Current Year:**
  `select first_of_year = convert(date,
     dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dayofyear,current_timestamp) , current_timestamp )
   ) ,`
- **Last Day of Current Year:**
  `select last_of_year = convert(date,
     dateadd(year,1,
       dateadd(day, -datepart(dayofyear,current_timestamp) , current_timestamp )
     )
   )`